# update set statement with a conditional expression

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

I need to do an update query where I'm setting a value based on results from a count query.  If the count returns no results, I want to set the status to 1, otherwise i want to set the status to 2.

Here's my attempt which doesn't work:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET status = ((select count(1) from TABLE_2) > 0 ? 1 : 2)
```

Also, I'm doing this within a mybatis xml file, so if there is some magic I can do in mybatis that would work too.

Comment: you want to set every row in table_1 with the same (decoded) count from table_2?  Or do you also want to join these tables? (get count from table_2 where some_id = table_1.some_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope DECODE Helps you! But all the rows in Status updated with same value.. You want it that way ?

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET status = (select DECODE(count(1),0,2,1) from TABLE_2);
```

Comment: Nice one. +1 on using `DECODE`. Almost forgot this existed `-)